# Why margin is not respected in this case?

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out why a margin is not respected when I resize to mobile view. If you resize the window, left margin is respected, however, right margin is not respected.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.banner-container {
  position: relative;
}

.banner-image {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.banner-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-width: 560px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding: 24px 0;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .banner-text {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}
```

```html
    <div class="banner-container">
      <div class="banner-image"></div>
      <span class="banner-text">Candidate Membership</span>
    </div>
```

I'd appreciate if someone could explain what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: This is a good candidate for flexbox layout.

Comment: @isherwood how is it so ? One element is absolutely positioned over the other one.

Comment: For one thing, it avoids the hassle of absolute positioning, which can be problematic when you resize for mobile.

Comment: @isherwood Thanks, for some reason I didn't even consider it. It makes sense.

Comment: Ideally you would set the box sizing to `content-box` to avoid this kind of issues. In that mode, the margin is part of the width of the element. You can check more in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The margin is there, but it is *added*  to the 100% `width` you defined. So the element's width including margins goes beyond the container width.

Comment: Thanks, that explains the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**.banner-text in media width : 80%**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.banner-container {
  position: relative;
}

.banner-image {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.banner-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-width: 560px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding: 24px 0;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .banner-text {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  .banner-text{
      width: 80%;
  }
}
```

```html
     <div class="banner-container">
      <div class="banner-image"></div>
      <span class="banner-text">Candidate Membership</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Some explanation would make your answer better.

Comment: thanks, even though it solves the problem, I was more interested in why it was not working. Thanks for the effort though.